# TypeScript compiler error on importation of Node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest) but the compiler is producing the following:

```
Client.ts(2,5): error TS2134: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. 
Variable 'XMLHttpRequest' must be of type '{ prototype: XMLHttpRequest; LOADING: number; 
DONE: number; UNSENT: number; OPENED: number; HEADERS_RECEIVED: number; new(): 
XMLHttpRequest; }', but here has type 'any'.
```

For reference the line producing the error is:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

Am I right in assuming that this is because node.d.ts doesn't have a definition for this module? If so how would I go about implementing the definition, the bit that has me confused is the `prototype` and `new()` having type `XMLHttpRequest`. Is this a recursive reference or will say an empty class declaration suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `XMLHttpRequest` is defined in lib.d.ts :

```
declare var XMLHttpRequest: {
    prototype: XMLHttpRequest;
    new (): XMLHttpRequest;
    LOADING: number;
    DONE: number;
    UNSENT: number;
    OPENED: number;
    HEADERS_RECEIVED: number;
}
```

This conflicts with your definition of `XMLHttpRequest` which is actually resolved to `any`

```
var XMLHttpRequest
```

If this lib is compatible with the browser `XMLHttpRequest` you can do (splitting declaration and assignment). This way the compiler doesn't try to redefine it as `any`:

```
 var XMLHttpRequest;
 XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

If not I suggest you use a different name, OR compile with --noLib compiler flag.

Comment: Thanks, the renaming worked. I wasn't aware definitions were being used from elsewhere, in hindsight it's obvious it would have to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes node.d.ts wouldn't have that declaration.

I have 2 possible options for you create a `node-XMLHttpRequest.d.ts` manually.  (I couldn't find one defined already) or use `var XMLHttpRequest = <any>(require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest);`

If you are using this library a lot in your code I would recommend defining the `node-XMLHttpRequest.d.ts` file to get the benefit from typescript type checking.